# Where-Object inconsistent behaviour between -InputObject parameter and pipe

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, powershell-5.1

#### Issue

Calling the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) cmdlet returns different outputs if the same [`PSObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psobject) is passed using the pipe or the `-InputObject` parameter:

1. When using the pipe, the condition is applied.
2. When using the `-InputObject` parameter, the condition is ignored.

#### Question

Why does the condition not apply when the `-InputObject` parameter is used?

#### MWE

Consider the following directory:

```
PS C:\> Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\tmp\mwe"


    Directory: C:\tmp\mwe


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        07/07/2021     15:51              0 a.txt
-a----        07/07/2021     15:54              0 b.csv
-a----        07/07/2021     15:53              0 c.log
```

##### Using pipe

When piping `Get-ChildItem` to `Where-Object`, the condition is properly applied and the text file is excluded from the output.

```
PS C:\> Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\tmp\mwe" | Where-Object -Property "Name" -NotMatch -Value "\.txt"


    Directory: C:\tmp\mwe


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        07/07/2021     15:54              0 b.csv
-a----        07/07/2021     15:53              0 c.log
```

##### Using `-InputObject` parameter

When using the `-InputObject` parameter, the condition is not applied and the text file is not excluded from the output.

```
PS C:\> Where-Object -InputObject (Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\tmp\mwe") -Property "Name" -NotMatch -Value "\.txt"


    Directory: C:\tmp\mwe


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        07/07/2021     15:51              0 a.txt
-a----        07/07/2021     15:54              0 b.csv
-a----        07/07/2021     15:53              0 c.log
```

Comment: In the last example you're asking `Where-Object` to evaluate the whole array as a single thing at once, as opposed to evaluating the items 1 by 1. Since `(Get-ChildItem).Name` evaluates to a collection where at least one item satisfies the condition, the entire array filters through.

Comment: I think this inconsistency is described in this PowerShell issue:  [`#4242` Consistently document a scalar -InputObject parameter as an implementation detail or make item-by-item processing cmdlets explicitly iterate over collections](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4242) from @mklement0

Answer (score 1):

After careful reading of the [pipeline documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines#one-at-a-time-processing), this distinct behaviour is indeed intended.

> Piping objects to a command is much like using a parameter of the command to submit the objects.
>
> [...]
>
> However, there's an important difference. When you pipe multiple objects to a command, PowerShell sends the objects to the command one at a time. When you use a command parameter, the objects are sent as a single array object. This minor difference has significant consequences.

Thank you [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68288806/where-object-inconsistent-behaviour-between-inputobject-parameter-and-pipe#comment120691752_68288806) and [iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68288806/where-object-inconsistent-behaviour-between-inputobject-parameter-and-pipe#comment120692210_68288806) for pointing that out in the comments.